# None of the valid provisionning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: beta-reports-active

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, in-house-distribution

Since the update for Xcode 6 (and probably the update to sdk8), I can't export my app for Entreprise distribution.

Otherwise, I can export, Xcode include a new provisionning generated by Xcode (prefixed by "XC: "), but it's the "Validate..." step who show me this warning.

Once on my server, the provisionning embedded (if it's embedded) in the app is "invalid", he not ask me to authorize the push notif.

If I build with this production provisionning in debug mode (with wire), i have the alert for push notification.

Finally, the complete warning:

`Failed to locate or generate matching signing assets:

Xcode attempted to locate or generate matching signing assets and failed to do so beacause of the following issues.

No matching provisionning profiles found for "Applications/myApp.app"
None of the valid provisionning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: beta-reports-active`

**Solution:**

When you export for Entreprise Distribution, you don't need to validate your project. The Validate option is only for appStore submition.

So, when you create a provisionning for entreprise Distribution, it's normal to have this warning. Everything else should function normally.

If you create the same provisionning for AppStore submition, you will not have this warning. I contacted Apple for this problem, and this is their solution.

It worked for me.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have the same problem. Updated to Xcode 6.1 today, but the error remains...

Comment: I just edited my post with the solution :)

Comment: Alright, I understand what you're saying -- but in my eyes it's not the same thing to "Submit" as to "Export". When I press Submit I get the option to "Submit for Enterprise" and specify meta information (i.e. generating a .plist). That's not happening when I just export to an .ipa.

Comment: You are right !
But, when you submit for entreprise, it generate .ipa AND the .plist.

If you have already this plist file, it's not required to submit, just export the ipa.

Edit: With Xcode 6 you can't submit for Entreprise. It's only export :)

Comment: You should write up your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: 
When you submit for entreprise, it generate .ipa AND the .plist. If you have already this plist file, it's not required to submit, just export the ipa. Edit: With Xcode 6 you can't submit for Entreprise. It's only export :)

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem
From developer.apple.com - You can't submit or validate your archive with adHoc profile.

To solve this problem - create new App Store profile. With this profile you will solve this problem )